# true identity establishment in Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When a user tries to register in the network how does the system ensure he/she is whom he/she claims to be? 
Another word, how should a identity be established in the network at the first place? You can not just assume who the users are by what they tell you during the registration step.

Answer (score 1):

The Fabric MSP (membership service provider) uses PKI certificates to establish identity within a "permissioned" network. The assumption that Hyperledger Fabric makes is that the members/participants in a "permissioned" network are all known to each other and bootstrap the network with a predefined set of agreed certificates that define the network's membership. The Hyperledger Fabric CA can be used to generate the certificates, or you can generate them from a your favorite CA. Please refer to the Hyperledger Fabric [documentation](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msp.html) for how certificates are managed.

Comment: Thanks Chris for adding some much needed detail!

Comment: Thx Dan ad Chris. However, such a assumption, " the members/participants in a "permissioned" network are all known to each other", is in question here, especially when the users are individuals but not entities. Current MSP implementation is segmented and there is no global identity management which, I feel, is something vital to tie all networks together?